# Explicit Ewald equations for dipole-dipole interaction in a simulation

Tags: quantum-spin, simulations, dipole

I'm starting to work with spin ice simulations and I found that it is usual to use the Ewald method for the long-range interactions computation (dipole-dipole in this case). Although I've been reading a lot about it, I'm finding really difficult to apply it to the simulations.

Does anybody knows where I can find an example of the Ewald implementation? I mean the code implementation. I read a lot of articles about the deduction of the method but I couldn't find some code exaples.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you actually search for Ewald summation code????? I am getting several links to Fortran implementations.

Comment: Yes, of course I did... where did you do the search?

Comment: On Google. Duckduckgo gets me to the same code, just a couple results further down. Bing seems to be a loser, but then it almost always is. I really don't care searching Yahoo...

Comment: Most Ewald codes are heavily optimised and therefore pretty much impenetrable. [This code](https://code.google.com/p/molecularmc/source/browse/trunk/classes/?r=37) looks relatively clean though (start in the ewald.h header).

Comment: There is something to be said for heavily optimized codes that are the standard of the art: they may actually be correct and/or work, whereas something that somebody wrote for their own amusement/training/to satisfy their "not invented here " monkey (I got one sitting on my shoulder every day!) may not be, even if it looks right. As a precaution I would suggest to study and run multiple pieces of code on the same test problems and compare outputs. If they agree, the better... and if they don't... you know why you don't want to put at least the results of one of them into your thesis!

Comment: CuriousOne, I'd looked in all the first page entries of duckduckgo and none of them satisfied me and I search in other places too with the same result. It's pretty obvious I did it or I wouldn't ask anything in the first place... Over that, I agree with your last comment. 
Lemon, thanks, I'll give it a look.

Comment: Well, you said you couldn't find code examples... and the code is right there. The better way to articulate the question would have been "I found code packages X, Y and Z and none of them are helpful because...". Having said that I understand and acknowledge your frustration. Scientific codes are all over the place in their quality, performance and overall usefulness. Many are the product of amateur coders who had a science problem and the code was their hack to solve that, but it was never meant to be production code until it became just that...